# Scipy minimize function result does not conform to constraints

Tags: python, scipy, minimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I used the Scipy minimize to find the set of parameters that minimize a differentiable function. There are 30 parameters a<sub>1</sub> to a<sub>6</sub>, b<sub>1</sub> to b<sub>6</sub>, c<sub>1</sub> to c<sub>6</sub>, d<sub>1</sub> to d<sub>6</sub> and e<sub>1</sub> to e<sub>6</sub>. Two constraints must be satisfied, the first one is that the sum of the solution array must add up to 1, and the second is that within the solution array of 30 items, 25 of them must be equal to 0. To be more specific, for each param group a,b,c,d,e , only one parameter in that group can have value that is greater than 0, and all the other 5 must have value equal to 0. The final result I get is an array which sum is approximately 2, and only 5 in the 30 params have the value of 0.

For the second constraint, i wrote a function like this and make it a constraint of type 'eq'

```
def group_constraint(weights):
    unique_groups = np.unique(groups)
    for group in unique_groups:
        group_weights = weights[groups == group]
        if np.sum(group_weights != 0) > 1:
            return np.sum(group_weights != 0) - 1
    return 0
```

The method I choose is SLSQP.

Comment: Please show your full invocation of `minimize`

Comment: `and the second is that within the solution array of 30 items, 25 of them must be equal to 0.` This seems like a constraint which is highly likely to cause minimize to get stuck in local minima. e.g. if it has the solution `a_1 = 1 a_2 = 0`, and there's a better solution at `a_1 = 0 a_2 = 1`, how is it supposed to get there if every step along the path is penalized?

Comment: Constraint is non differentiable. You need integral constraints. If your objective is linear, move to MILP.

Comment: If you choose one of 6 variables 5 times, that's 6**5 possibilities, or only 7776 possibilities. What if you used brute force to decide which variables to pick, and only use minimize to choose what value to assign those variables?

Comment: Thank you for your great explanations and suggestions. I tried removing the constraint and looping thru all the combinations. It took me less than 10 mins and the returned array accurately sums to 1.